# html tags inside mathjax

Tags: html, mathjax

I already know that mathjax allows very limited html codes inside math areas, however, I have a multiple page document, each having a number of equations, so for `\eqref{}` to work properly, I have wrapped these commands in a clickable `<span>` which direct to the page containing the addressed equation, before the page is scrolled to the equation somewhere withing that page.

The relevant part of the markdown application is, first,

```
content=content
    .replace(/(\\ref\{[^\}]+\})/g, "<span class='eqCitationSpan'>$1</span>")
    .replace(/(\\eqref\{[^\}]+\})/g, "<span class='eqCitationSpan'>$1</span>")
```

and then,

```
// to handle cross-referencing the equations in MathJax, due to the multipage nature of the document
var perPageEqs=[];
MathJax.Hub.Queue(
    function () {
        for(pageNum=0; pageNum<totalPageNumber; pageNum++){
            var jax = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("resultPage-"+pageNum);
            var neWLabelsInPage=[];
            for (var i=0, l=jax.length; i<l; i++) {
                jax[i].originalText.replace(/\\label\{([^\}]+)\}/g, function(x,y){
                    neWLabelsInPage.push(y);
                    return false;
                });
            }
            perPageEqs.push(neWLabelsInPage);
        }


        var eqCitationArray = document.getElementsByClassName("eqCitationSpan");
        var eqsOnWhichPage;
        for(var i=0, l=eqCitationArray.length; i<l; i++) {
            var key=eqCitationArray[i].innerHTML
                .replace(/.*\\ref\{([^\}]+)\}.*/g,"$1").replace(/.*\\eqref\{([^\}]+)\}.*/g,"$1");
            eqsOnWhichPage=perPageEqs.findIndex(function(x) {
                return x.indexOf(key) !== -1;
            });
            eqCitationArray[i].outerHTML=
                "<span class='eqCitationSpan' onclick='currentPage="+eqsOnWhichPage+"; changePage();'>"
                    +eqCitationArray[i].innerHTML
                +"</span>";
        }
    }
);
```

Everything works well except when I want to refer to an equation from within another equation. In that case, MathJax doesn't compile the equation at all, but only the command `\eqref{}` inside the equation. **I know it is intended to be so**, *but then any work around for such problems?*

Comment: Without an example of what you've tried, it's hard to give any practical advice. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some advice.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to add a class around parts of an TeX input fragment. There's `\class{name}{math}` for that https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#html - have you tried that?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger, No I didn't, since actually I'm not adding a mere class name to the math references to give them a style, instead, I was trying to add an onclick event-listener to \ref{} and \eqref{}, and the class name was a mean to collect all the \ref's and \eqref's but not all the math.

Comment: Right, and that part should work once you have added the classes in a way that doesn't break MathJax. The only additional caveat is that you need to wait for MathJax to render, but a mutation observer should work for that.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger, your idea worked fine, only there was one problem: if I use replace(/(\\eqref\{[^\}]+\})/g, "\\class{eqCitationSpan}{$1}") it works inside the equations, but not in the main text that shows e.g. \class{eqCitationSpan}{(10)}, and if I use replace(/(\\eqref\{[^\}]+\})/g, "$\\class{eqCitationSpan}{$1}$"), then it works fine inside the main script, but shows $(10)$ inside the equations, which is no nice. I solved the problem, although, not in a natural way. By the way, if you add your comment above as an answer I'll be happy to select it as accepted :)

Answer (score 4):

MathJax will not process math that contains HTML tags (other than a select few), so you will not be able to do the kind of replacements inside an expression like you are attempting to do here.

You can, however, use MathJax itself to handle the cross-page lining that I think you are trying to accomplish.  Here's one approach:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
(function () {
  //
  // The values from MathJax.Extensions["TeX/AMSmath"].labels
  //   on all the linked pages.
  //
  var labels = {
    xyz2: {tag: "2", id: "mjx-eqn-xyz2"}
  };
  //
  //  Maps tag IDs to pages on which they occur.
  //
  var urls = {
    "mjx-eqn-xyz2": "link-cross-page2.html"
  };

  //
  //  Add the labels for the other pages when AMSmath is loaded.
  //
  MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX AMSmath Ready", function () {
    var keys = Object.keys(labels);
    for (var i = 0, m = keys.length; i < m; i++) {
      MathJax.Extension["TeX/AMSmath"].labels[keys[i]] = labels[keys[i]];
    }
  });

  //
  //  Configure TeX to use the external page url rather than the base url
  //    if the id is on a different page.
  //
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {
      equationNumbers: {
        formatURL(id, base) {
          return (urls[id] || base) + '#' + id;
        }
      }
    }
  });
})();
</script>
```

Put this **before** the script that loads MathJax.js itself.  You will need to collect the data from `MathJax.Extension["TeX/AMSmath"].labels` from all the pages you want to link to and put that in the `var labels` above (combine the data from all the pages into one object), and create the mapping from ids to page urls in `var urls` above.  In this example, there is `\label{xyz2}\tag{2}` in the file `link-cross-page2.html`, and any `\ref{xyz2}` on the page containing this code will link to `link-cross-page2.html#mjx-eqn-2`.

The rest of the code simply copies your labels into the AMSmath labels list when it is loaded, and configures TeX's `formatURL()` function to look up the file in your list and use that if it exists, otherwise it uses the base URL of the page.

Note that this does require that equation numbers are different across the pages, but I assume that is the case for you, otherwise you could not tell which page to link to.

Comment: interesting how you applied url change over equations' numbers. However, I don't have really different HTML pages each having its own url, instead, I have different divs, only one being shown at a time while the others being hidden, like how several tabs are used in one single page. The function that is to control which page to be shown is `changePage()`, and it works based on the current value of the global variable `currentPage`. I added more relevant details of the code to my question, and apologize for the question being ambiguous on what I meant by "page".

Comment: See this [MathJax issue](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2594) for how to use MathJax version 3 to handle both the mutli-page links (as described here) together with the single-page multi-div approach request by @owari.